# Change two colors in non random order

Tags: javascript

I need to change background color of div element every time i reload the page.
And i want to change it with two colors that will not be repeated after reload.
THis is the code with random switch of two colors:

```
var bgcolorlist=new Array("#BAF3C3", "#c3baf3")

$("#datetime").css("backgroundcolor",bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]);
```

How to switch the colors without repeat them?

Comment: so you only load the page twice or what?

Comment: Use the localStorage to save the previous pick and compare with the new one.

Comment: `backgroundcolor` should be `backgroundColor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in previous posts, you will have to save the last color used. You could use cookies, or the localstorage like in this fiddle (on stackoverflow localStorage in snippets is not possible)

https://jsfiddle.net/zh07xfu0/

```
var bgcolorlist = new Array("#BAF3C3", "#c3baf3")
var index = localStorage.getItem("color") == 1 ? 0 : 1;
$("body").css("background-color", bgcolorlist[index]);
localStorage.setItem("color", index);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might just toggle depending on the number of history entries:

```
 const backgroundColor = history.length % 2 ? "#BAF3C3": "#c3baf3"
```

Or as Viktor pointed out, just store a small flag in the localStorage:

```
 let backgroundColor = "#BAF3C3";

 if(localStorage.changeBackground) {
   localStorage.changeBackground = ""
 } else {
   localStorage.changeBackground = "1"
   backgroundColor = "#c3baf3"
}
```

Comment: Only reloading the page shouldn't change history's length.

Comment: And localStorage casts whatever value you pass to it as string, so after first run of your code, you'll always have `localStorage.changeBackground` set as truthy.

Comment: @kaiido i thought that setting to `undefined` would behave similar to `removeItem`, seems i were wrong ...

Comment: Yes, you would have to `delete` it if you wish to use the property syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `background` instead of `backgroundcolor` like this:

```js
var bgcolorlist=new Array("#BAF3C3", "#c3baf3")

$("#datetime").css("background",bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='datetime'>Some content </div>
```

`backgroundcolor` is not a valid css property. To check the randomness of the background color, click on `Run code snippet` multiple times. You will see that the background color is randomly changed.

You can also use `background-color` css property like,

```js
var bgcolorlist=new Array("#BAF3C3", "#c3baf3")

$("#datetime").css("background-color",bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='datetime'>Some content </div>
```

For non-repeating behaviour, you can use `localStorage` to save the index value of the `bgcolorlist` which you can get on each page load and skip that index value at the time of applying the background color.

Comment: But it should not be repeated.

Comment: @SachiTekina thanks for pointing. I added few lines to describe that